# Cannot log stack traces with apollo server

Tags: apollo-server, graphql-js

I'm building a graphql application with apollo server and I'm having trouble figuring out how to log stack traces serverside in production mode.

I found [these docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#omitting-or-including-stacktrace) but it's not clear how to correctly log stack traces in production.

I have the following `formatError` function:

```
    formatError: ((err) => {
      console.error(err.originalError)
      return err
  })
```

and when one of my resolvers throws an error with `NODE_ENV=production` I see the following output:

```
Error: Unexpected error value: "could not get config value"
    at locatedError (/tripvector/node_modules/graphql/error/locatedError.js:24:9)
    at /tripvector/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:491:54
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async execute (/tripvector/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:204:20)
    at async processGraphQLRequest (/tripvector/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:138:28)
    at async processHTTPRequest (/tripvector/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runHttpQuery.js:187:30)
```

However, when I run in debug mode, the original error is printed as I expect:

```
Error: could not get config value
    at validate (file:///Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend/lib/settings/settings.js:11:15)
    at getGoogleSecret (file:///Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend/lib/settings/settings.js:29:12)
    at Object.loginWithGoogle (file:///Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend/api/users/graphql/mutations.js:141:30)
    at field.resolve (/Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/utils/schemaInstrumentation.js:52:26)
    at executeField (/Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:469:20)
    at /Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:365:22
    at promiseReduce (/Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/promiseReduce.js:23:9)
    at executeFieldsSerially (/Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:361:43)
    at executeOperation (/Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:335:14)
    at execute (/Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:130:20)
```

I throw the error with the following code:

```
function validate(val) {
    if (!val) {
        throw new Error('could not get config value')
    }
    return val
}
```

How can I correctly configure apollo server to print stack traces for errors, even in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I found the answer 2 minutes after asking. I was doing some silly error catching and rethrowing in promises which is why this problem was happening only in production.

Comment: can you pls share solution :)

Comment: the above solution works, I was doing some weird promise/resolve stuff elsewhere in the app and when the error finally reached the `formatError` handler it wasn't an error object but a string which caused the problem.